# How to browse for a folder on OS X?

Tags: lotus-notes

I've got a function in a Notes app running on the Windows Notes client which allows you to choose a folder into which files get downloaded.  It uses a call to shell32.  It, of course, won't work on a OS X.  I found code to drop files into the TMP folder of Windows, MAC, and Linux which works. But I would rather it prompt for a folder and not just use the TMP folder.  Anyone know how to browse for a folder on OS X?

thanks
clem

Comment: what version of notes are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use OpenFileDialog method but you must have to select a file and then retrive his path removing the file name.